# RegKeyValue returning nonsense data

Tags: c++, winapi

```
char value[255];
DWORD BufferSize = 8192;

RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"ProductName", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, &value, &BufferSize);

cout << value;
```

After RegKeyValue() runs, it appears that value is

```
    value   0x0034f50c "ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ...  char[255]
```

What's going on here?

**Note:** RegKeyValue() returns 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't check the return value of `RegGetValue`. Most likely the call failed and the buffer `value` was never assigned anything. Always check return values.

From the code we can see, I note that you are lying about the buffer size. You say that it is 8192 bytes. But you only allocated 255 bytes. You are also calling the Unicode version of the API, but passing in a `char` buffer. If you are expecting string data then you need to supply a buffer of wide characters. The Unicode version of this API will return string data as UTF-16 encoded text.

Once you get all that sorted you next need to check what type is stored in that value. You are passing NULL for the type parameter. Pass a pointer to a variable and find out whether or not a string really is stored
 there. You will also need to read how many bytes are read and set the null-terminator in your buffer accordingly.

Comment: I should have used WCHAR instead of char. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here.

1. Make sure the return value of [RegGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is `ERROR_SUCCESS`.  If it is not, the routine failed.  Also, you can check to see what was written into `BufferSize`, as `RegGetValue` specifies the number of bytes written.
2. You're passing in a buffer defined as `char value[255];`, then specifying it's length as `8192`.  This can cause a buffer overrun.

Comment: It is returning ERROR_SUCCESS, just checked. I kinda copied the value[255] part from a code snippet I found that was allegedly working. How do I know what size does it need to be set to?

Comment: @dsp_099 Your size should match the buffer size you specify.  If you want to pass 8192, make the array 8192 as well.  (Also, if you're using unicode, you should use an appropriate character type, too)